# AirPlay works great with iOS but quite bad on macOS

Tags: macos, appletv, airplay

AirPlay freezes if streamed from Mac (I have 2 Macs with latest macOS and they have the same issue).

It works great from my iPhone instead.

I have Apple TV 3rd generation with latest TVOS installed.

I've also tried a different modem and I still get issue using the macOS only.

Any clue?

Comment: How are the Macs connected to the network? (cable, wifi, etc) - How is the iPhone connected to the network? - How is the AppleTV connected to the network?

Comment: @jksoegaard All devices use the same wifi